# What is the Time Complexity of std::multiset::count in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, multiset

I am confused about the number of operations that takes place when calling count(x) for some **element x** in a multiset of **size n**.

Am I correct that the number of operations is log(n) + #_of_matches_of_x, meaning logarithmic in the number of elements in the multiset, plus the number of matches of the target element x among all elements in the multiset?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: When in doubt, check a reference site like: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/count

Comment: I did, I just didn't understand what the linear part of the time complexity meant.

Comment: linear means O(N)

Comment: But more specifically, in terms of the number of operations...

Comment: Is it the number of matches of the target element?

Comment: If size of container = N and number of elements you're counting = M, then the complexity is `log(N) + M`

Comment: What do you mean by "number of elements you're counting"?

Comment: If the multiset is of ints, and you're counting the number of 5's, the "number of elements you're counting" is the number of 5's in your multiset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [reference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/count) has mentioned, the complexity of count is:

> Logarithmic in the size of the container **plus** linear in the number of
> the elements found.

The reason is that `std::multiset` is a tree-like data structure with a container at each tree node. So, for when calling `std::multiset::count`, you should first find the key in the tree `O(log(All elements))` and then count the elements in that found node `(O(found elements))`.

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/count/) clearly states that the complexity of multiset::count is

> Logarithmic in size and linear in the number of matches.

Or you can check out this [one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/count).

> Logarithmic in the size of the container plus linear in the number of the elements found.

Well, I pulled out an interesting article for you. ([Link](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/65786))